# JSF build time is slow

Tags: performance, tomcat, jsf, primefaces, omnifaces

I have JSF 2.2.6 + Primefaces 6.0 + Omnifaces 1.7 + Tomcat 8.0.37 (embedded with spring boot)  Webapp.
The application load page is very slow. I performed audit in google and the time is  around 10s.

I checked Phases and the most consuming is render time. Then I check create/build/render time and I noticed that build takes at most. Around 8s of all. 
Is it because I use a lot of composite components or maybe omnifaces are to old?

Comment: If possible update to the newest versions and if the problem still exist try to find out the issue(s) step by step. Write log entries in your java code after each logic and check the entries if something needs too much time. If you can't find the cause of the problem in your java code remove components step by step to find out what is causing the issue.

Comment: Also make sure that javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD is "-1" and javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE is "Production" in production environment. Don't execute business logic on every invokation of any getter as they are invoketd several times per request. View BUILD phase duration also correlates strongly to the number of components present in your view - this sadly ist true for every even tiny AJAX request.

Comment: Yes, I know that so it's strange for me. But there is around 2k nodes...